# Change Background color for a specific column in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the background color of a specif column in a HTML table. Is it possible to use a  property to do it. I found the way to do it with rows.

```
tr.even {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Why not put an id on the columns so you can change it from css?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I color table columns using CSS without coloring individual cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234480/can-i-color-table-columns-using-css-without-coloring-individual-cells)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try using the colgroup tag and combining that with the span attribute. that way if you have 3 columns for instance, you can do

```
<colgroup>
<col span="2" id="something">
<col id="something2">
</colgroup>
```

then you can style that whole column with css.

ex:

```
#something2 {background-color:red;}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to style the background of a column, and not a row, you can try something like this (below). You'll need to change the selectors to match your HTML.

`td:first-child { background-color: #ccc; }`

Below is a link to a fiddle, along with a way to add classes via JS. There are many ways, but since you are dealing with columns, remember that the CSS is being applied to the same `td` in each row you want to style.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85k3J/)**

Comment: Note :Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector

Comment: You are correct @ZIP. That's why I included the JS and/or class version as well. I feel for those still supporting IE8...

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers, you could use the [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) selector:

```
element:nth-child(1) {
    background-color:...
}
```

Or if you wanted to use jQuery, use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(element).eq(0).css("background-color","...");
```

<sub>Note: the CSS `nth-child` selector is 1-based while the jQuery `eq` selector is 0-based.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr:even').css('background-color', '#e5e5e5');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:even](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) and [:odd](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector:

```
$( "table tr:even" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
$( "table tr:odd" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

If you want to target the column then use:

```
$('table tr > :nth-child(even)').css('background-color','white');
$('table tr > :nth-child(odd)').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use just HTML  and css you have to give every div even and odd class respectively.
then give different css in you css file  for both even and odd class.

```
<tr class="even"></tr>
<tr class="odd"></tr>
<tr class="even"></tr>


    tr.even {
        background-color: white;
    }

    tr.odd {
        background-color: black;
    }
```

if you want more dynamic way ,mean don't give class manually jquery will serach  and add even odd div and give them specific class

Use  jquery

```
$('tr:odd').addClass("odd")
$('tr:even').addClass("even")
```

and your css will be like this

```
tr.even {
    background-color: white;
}

tr.odd {
    background-color: black;
}
```