# Can I color table columns using CSS without coloring individual cells?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to color spans of columns all the way down.  See, starting example below:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Motor</th>
    <th colspan="3">Engine</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th colspan="2">Body</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I am looking for a better way (less code, non-individual coloring) to color, for example, "Engine" and "Body" spans, including all the cells underneath them in `#DDD`

```html
<style>
  .color {
    background-color: #DDD
  }
</style>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Motor</th>
    <th colspan="3" class="color">Engine</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="color">Body</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="color">2</td>
    <td class="color">3</td>
    <td class="color">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="color">6</td>
    <td class="color">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="color">1</td>
    <td class="color">2</td>
    <td class="color">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="color">5</td>
    <td class="color">6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @zipzit: There's nothing wrong with tables if you actually *need* a table - i.e. if the data is tabular in nature (like a table of products with prices). The criticism of tables is against using them as a layout tool.

Comment: Wonder how this entered Hot Network Questions

Comment: it was asked yesterday and as of right now, has 24 upvotes on Q and 43 on A, and the accepted Answer was and is still being upvoted like crazy

Comment: @Mr.Alien Something similar happened with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26126017/621962). I'm not sure why it got so many votes so quickly but I'm hesitant to ask too many questions since my answer benefits from the attention. :P

Comment: people like to learn things they didn't know, be it a documented peculiarity of jQuery number parsing, or an HTML tag/concept that does neat things, they didn't know about :)

Comment: @canon heh yes, anyways decent answer...

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Yes, you can... using the [`<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) element:

```css
.grey {
  background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.25);
}
.red {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.25);
}
.blue {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.25);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="grey" />
    <col class="red" span="3" />
    <col class="blue" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th colspan="3">color 1</th>
      <th>color 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>red</td>
      <td>red</td>      
      <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<sub>**Note**: You can use the [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col#attr-span) attribute to make the col definition apply to more than one column.

**See also**: [`<colgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup)</sub>

Comment: Note that you'll need `<col span="3" />` for the spanning columns.

Comment: It’s rather pointless to use a `colgroup` that contains all columns.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It gets parsed that way regardless of whether or not you specify it -just like `<tbody>`. I simply prefer to specify.

Comment: I see that the use of the `col` tag is not that common, but I use it always for column widths

Comment: In case anybody else is curious why this works, or which CSS properties can be used on columns, the pertinent sections of the CSS 2.1 spec are [17.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns) and [17.5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layers).

Comment: @netrox Why earlier? Did you do that by JavaScript before?

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `nth-child` selector for that:

```css
tr td:nth-child(2),
tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">headline 1</th>
    <th>headline 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column 1</td>
    <td>column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column 1</td>
    <td>column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column 1</td>
    <td>column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Styling `col` themselves is way better than this (cleaner and faster).

Answer (score 9):

It is generally simplest to style cells (by column if desired), but columns can be styled, in different ways. One simple way is to wrap columns in a `colgroup` element and set styles on it. Example:

```html
<style>
.x {
    background-color: #DDD
}
</style>
<table border="1">
<col>
<colgroup class=x>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
</colgroup>
<col>
<colgroup class=x>
  <col>
  <col>
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Motor</th>
    <th colspan="3" class="color">Engine</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="color">Body</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="color">2</td>
    <td class="color">3</td>
    <td class="color">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="color">6</td>
    <td class="color">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td class="color">1</td>
    <td class="color">2</td>
    <td class="color">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="color">5</td>
    <td class="color">6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If the individual `col` elements inside the `colgroup`s don't need to be styled individually, you can also set the `span` attribute on the `colgroup` itself - `<colgroup span="2">` - *instead* of placing `col` elements inside it.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the `nth-child` css pseudo-class for this:

```
tr td:nth-child(2), tr th:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(3), tr td:nth-child(4), tr th:nth-child(4), tr td:nth-child(6), tr td:nth-child(7){
    background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```css
tr td:nth-child(2),
tr th:nth-child(2),
tr td:nth-child(3),
tr td:nth-child(4),
tr th:nth-child(4),
tr td:nth-child(6),
tr td:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Motor</th>
    <th colspan="3">Engine</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th colspan="2">Body</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

The following implement's the nth-child selector and should work...

```
<style type="text/css">
    th:nth-child(2),
    th:nth-child(4)
    {
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
    }

    td:nth-child(2), 
    td:nth-child(3),
    td:nth-child(4),
    td:nth-child(6),
    td:nth-child(7)
    {
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You probably want a `>` between tr and td, since you went to the trouble of selecting tds only inside trs only inside tables... (mind the tablegroups.)

Comment: Thanks for answer, this is different solution

Comment: This is an overkill. Over-specifying is bad for performance. `table tr td` is redundant as `td`s are always inside `tr` and `table`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS3:
http://jsfiddle.net/snuggles08/bm98g8v8/

```html
<style>
  .table td:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: red;
  }
  .table td:nth-of-type(5) {
    background: blue;
  }
  .table td:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: green;
  }
  .table td:nth-of-type(7) {
    background: lime;
  }
  .table td:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: skyblue;
  }
  .table td:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: darkred;
  }
  .table td:nth-of-type(6) {
    background: navy;
  }
</style>
Styled table:
<table border="1" class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>Unstyled table:
<table border="1" class="table2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

My version using nth-child expressions:

Using the CSS concept of cascade rules to first coloring the cells and then to uncolor the ones i want to be transparent. The first selector selects all the cells after the first one, and the second one selects the fifth cell to be transparent.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  /* colored */
  td:nth-child(n+2) { background-color: #ddd }
  /* uncolored */
  td:nth-child(5) { background-color: transparent }
</style>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Motor</th>
    <th colspan="3">Engine</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th colspan="2">Body</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Check this interesting reference:
http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question with a lot of great answers.  Just wanted to add the `-n` and `nth-last-child` selectors that haven't yet been mentioned.  They're helpful when applying CSS to multiple columns but may not know the number of columns prior to styling, or have multiple tables with varying widths.

```
/* Select the first two */
table tr td:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* Select all but the first two */
table tr td:not(:nth-child(-n + 2)) {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}

/* Select last two only */
table tr td:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
  background-color:mistyrose;
}

/* Select all but the last two */
table tr td:not(:nth-last-child(-n + 2)) {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3rpf5oht/2/