# html: different colors for both row and column of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, colors, row

How to write a css code in html code for creating a table like the following:

different colors for both alternative column and row

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: This question has been solved by setting the column in blue and light blue first then use the CSS-selector as the following:

Comment: table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+0),tr:nth-child(10n+1),tr:nth-child(10n+2),tr:nth-child(10n+3),tr:nth-child(10n+4){
 background: pink;
}

Comment: table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+0) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: #EAFFDB;}

Comment: table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+1) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: #EAFFDB;}

Comment: table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+2) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: #EAFFDB;}

Comment: table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+3) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: #EAFFDB;}

Comment: table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+4) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: #EAFFDB;}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS-Selector nth-child.
This selector selects for example the second row.

```
table tr:nth-child(2){
     background: red;
}
```

To have different coloured columns, you can use the following selector. 
This will color the second column.

```
tr td:nth-child(2){
    background: red;
}
```

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234480/can-i-color-table-columns-using-css-without-coloring-individual-cells)

To select a specifig cell use both at one time:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2){
    background: red;
}
```

More on this Website: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement so called [even and odd rules](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html), such as:

```
tr:nth-child(even)
tr:nth-child(odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

the style will be implemented based on td and for red blue rows you can add class to (tr) or you can use nth child with number there on tr : `tr:nth-child(6)`

`tr td:nth-child(even)  {background:red;} 
tr td:nth-child(odd)  {background:pink;}`

Answer (score 0):

This question has been solved by setting the column in blue and light blue first then use the CSS-selector as the following:

```
table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+0),tr:nth-child(10n+1),tr:nth-child(10n+2),tr:nth-child(10n+3),tr:nth-child(10n+4){background: pink; }  

table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+0) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: red;} 
table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+1) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: red;} 
table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+2) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: red;} 
table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+3) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: red;}
table.tb1 tr:nth-child(10n+4) td:nth-child(2n+1){background: red;}
```

Thank you very much for helping me!